# Calling Snowflake Stored Procedure from Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake stored procedure which exports data to S3 based on dynamic input parameters. I am trying to set this up via tableau, so that I can use tableau parameters and call the snowflake stored procedure from Tableau, is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

While there's no straightforward solution, you could accomplish this task with a series of Snowflake facilities:

- Create a task that monitors `information_schema.query_history()` every X minutes.
- Have this task check for queries executed under a Tableau session.
- If any of these queries have a parameter set by your Tableau dashboard that indicates the user wants to export these results, then do so.

You can check that a session was initiated by Tableau searching the query history for `ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = { "tableau-query-origins": { "query-category": "Data" } }`.